# Python creating a nested html table from query

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have the following data:

```
[{"Name": "CREATIVE OIL & GAS OPERATING,LLC", "District": "1", "County": 
"GONZALES (TX)", "OFS Region": "GULF COAST", "Lease Name": "ALFORD"}, 
{"Name": "KALER ENERGY CORP.", "District": "2", "County": "JACKSON (TX)", 
"OFS Region": "GULF COAST", "Lease Name": "DUGGER UNIT"}, {"Name": "ENCANA 
OIL & GAS(USA) INC.", "District": "2", "County": "PECOS (TX)", "OFS 
Region": "PERMIAN BASIN", "Lease Name": "HONS UNIT"}]
```

I am trying to get the data into this format:

```html
<h3>OFS Region: GULF COAST</h3>
<H4>County: Gonzales</H4>

<table style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Lease Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CREATIVE OIL & GAS OPERATING,LLC</td>
    <td>ALFORD</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<H4>County: Jackson</H4>

<table style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Lease Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>KALER ENERGY CORP.</td>
    <td>DUGGER UNIT</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<h3>OFS Region: Permian Basin</h3>
<H4>County: Pecos</H4>

<table style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Lease Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ENCANA OIL & GAS(USA) INC.</td>
    <td>HONS UNIT</td>

  </tr>
```

So basically I am trying to figure out how to dynamically create tables on some of the columns ('Name', 'Lease Name') and separate and sort those by a couple other columns ('OFS Region', 'District', 'County') and its giving me hell. I have tried putting the data in json, defaultdict, nested_dict, pandas pivot_table and a couple other ways.

Here are some examples of what I have tried:

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
d = defaultdict(defaultdict)
for row in rows:
    ofs_region = row[3]
    district = row[1]
    county = row[2]
    name = row[0]
    lease_name = row[4]

    a = {'Name': name, 'Lease Name': lease_name}

    d[ofs_region][district][county] = a
```

Another example:

```
b = {}
for row in rows:
    ofs_region = row[3]
    district = row[1]
    county = row[2]
    name = row[0]
    lease_name = row[4]

    list = [name, lease_name]

    if ofs_region not in b:
        b[ofs_region] = ofs_region

    if district not in b[ofs_region]:
        b[ofs_region][district]  = district
        b[ofs_region] = ({'district': {district: {'name': name, 'lease name': lease_name}}})

    if district not in a[ofs_region]:
        a[ofs_region][district] = district
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to store the data, and then format the table with `str.join`:

```
data = [{"Name": "CREATIVE OIL & GAS OPERATING,LLC", "District": "1", "County": "GONZALES (TX)", "OFS Region": "GULF COAST", "Lease Name": "ALFORD"}, {"Name": "KALER ENERGY CORP.", "District": "2", "County": "JACKSON (TX)", "OFS Region": "GULF COAST", "Lease Name": "DUGGER UNIT"}, {"Name": "ENCANA OIL & GAS(USA) INC.", "District": "2", "County": "PECOS (TX)", "OFS Region": "PERMIAN BASIN", "Lease Name": "HONS UNIT"}]
class Company:
  def __init__(self, d):
    self.__dict__ = {a.replace(' ', '_').lower():b for a, b in d.items()}

companies = [Company(i) for i in data]
block = """
<h3>OFS Region: {}</h3>
<H4>County: {}</H4>

<table style="width:30%">
 <tr>
  <th>Company</th>
  <th>Lease Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>{}</td>
 <td>{}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
""" 
final_result = '\n\n'.join(block.format(i.ofs_region, i.county, i.name, i.lease_name) for i in companies)
```

Output:

```
<h3>OFS Region: GULF COAST</h3>
<H4>County: GONZALES (TX)</H4>

<table style="width:30%">
<tr>
 <th>Company</th>
 <th>Lease Name</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>CREATIVE OIL & GAS OPERATING,LLC</td>
<td>ALFORD</td>
 </tr>
 </table>



<h3>OFS Region: GULF COAST</h3>
<H4>County: JACKSON (TX)</H4>

<table style="width:30%">
<tr>
<th>Company</th>
 <th>Lease Name</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>KALER ENERGY CORP.</td>
 <td>DUGGER UNIT</td>
 </tr>
</table>



 <h3>OFS Region: PERMIAN BASIN</h3>
 <H4>County: PECOS (TX)</H4>

<table style="width:30%">
<tr>
 <th>Company</th>
 <th>Lease Name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
 <td>ENCANA OIL & GAS(USA) INC.</td>
 <td>HONS UNIT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not quite what I'm looking to do. The issue I am having is that some items are may share a county for example. I want all items with the same county to be in the same table. All tables with the same district should be under the one district heading, not have the district heading repeated every table. The same for the OFS Region.